# How do we separate a column into multiple ones based on "|"?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a tibble.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(
  id = 1:4,
  genres = c("Action|Adventure|Science Fiction|Thriller", 
        "Adventure|Science Fiction|Thriller",
        "Action|Crime|Thriller",
        "Family|Animation|Adventure|Comedy|Action")
)
df
```

[image]

I want to separate the genres by "|" and empty columns filled with NA.

This is what I did:

```
df %>% 
  separate(genres, into = c("genre1", "genre2", "genre3", "genre4", "genre5"), sep = "|")
```

However, it's being separated after each letter.

[image]

Comment: Use `cSplit` from `splitstackshape` package, `cSplit(df, "genres", "|")`.

Comment: Please include the code that does the splitting.

Answer (score 2):

I think you haven't included `into`:

```
df <- tibble::tibble(
  id = 1:4,
  genres = c("Action|Adventure|Science Fiction|Thriller", 
             "Adventure|Science Fiction|Thriller",
             "Action|Crime|Thriller",
             "Family|Animation|Adventure|Comedy|Action")
)
df %>% tidyr::separate(genres, into = c("genre1", "genre2", "genre3", 
                 "genre4", "genre5"))
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 6
     id    genre1    genre2    genre3   genre4   genre5
* <int>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>    <chr>    <chr>
1     1    Action Adventure   Science  Fiction Thriller
2     2 Adventure   Science   Fiction Thriller     <NA>
3     3    Action     Crime  Thriller     <NA>     <NA>
4     4    Family Animation Adventure   Comedy   Action
```

*Edit*: Or as RichScriven wrote in the comments, `df %>% tidyr::separate(genres, into = paste0("genre", 1:5))`. For separating on `|` exactly, use `sep = "\\|"`.

Comment: Or `into = paste0("genre", 1:5)`

Comment: @RichScriven Even better!

Comment: @RobertMc- sorry for my incomplete code, I have made edits. The code you have provided splits Science and Fiction into separate columns, which is not what I want. I want Science Fiction to be in the same column and separation based only on "|".

Comment: @arjan-hada Ah okay. I added that in to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is what helped, writing regex properly.

```
df %>% 
  separate(genres, into = paste0("genre", 1:5), sep = "\\|")
```